# Sharepoint List lookup Issues

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, powerapps, power-automate, powerapps-canvas

How do I use the input of a previous column to determine the list lookup list for a drop down menu? My goal is to have a column that has 3 options to choose from and based off what option is chosen in that column, the next column will display options available corresponding to the choice in the previous column.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KyIJN.png)

There are more options for each Size / Dieline that are not displayed in the image.

In Size /Dieline the options are 473mL 109mm LF, 355mL 110mm LF, and 355mL 109mm LF.

I want the options in the second column to match the corresponding list options for each of the above. Currently, they only reads the 473mL list of options.

I have tried lookups, linked list, calculated columns, couldn't figure out the power automate flow.
I would appreciate some guidance as I am very new to this.

Comment: power apps is tagged in your question, but from your description it seems you have so far only tried to achieve your goal using SharePoint and Power Automate. Have you also tried customizing the SharePoint list form using PowerApps?

Comment: you can easily do cascading thing using powerapps.

Answer (score 0):

you can easily do cascading thing using powerapps. In SharePoint you need to create a (lookup) list that defines these relationships between size/dieline and pallet size test column. In powerapps customised form/canvas app, I assume you have separate dropdowns for both of these columns. You can easily lookup the list in SharePoint by adding that list as a data source. Then using 'Lookup' formula you can get items from look up list corresponding to selected value from size/dieline dropdown and store the result in a collection. Then you can use the resultant collection to set the 'items' property of 'pallet size test' dropdown